# Can I see a transaction sent to me if I haven't downloaded the whole blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, synchronization

Last received block was 12 weeks ago, and I'm still syncing. I have moved some bitcoins to this wallet from another, but I still can't see it in my inbox after a day.

Is it because I don't have all the blocks?

Comment: Make sure to run the latest version, as quite a few improvements have been over over the last few releases.

Comment: Is that a yes, or a no?

Comment: Did you move these coins using the same wallet you are now trying to look the transfers up? In that case you should see the transactions. If you used some other tool then you might not see the transactions in this wallet until you have caught up with the blockchain to the point were the transactions were confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you moved the bitcoins less than 12 weeks ago, then that is why you don't see them yet.  There are several online bitcoin blockchain explorers that will let you enter your public address and see its balance and transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/) to see transactions sent to your address.  Just go to https://blockchain.info/ and enter your address in the search field.

Comment: Note that you are publishing your interest in the respective address to this company, which depending on your use case could hurt your privacy.

Comment: True.  If that's a concern, use TOR.

Comment: is that a yes or a no to my question?

Comment: It's a 'yes' if using blockchain.info as a workaround (as opposed to use the wallet program that is not working for you) is acceptable to you for viewing your transactions.  Otherwise, it's a 'no'.